# Yocto Implementation of QEMU

Tags: qemu, yocto

What exactly is the difference between the Yocto Implementation of QEMU and QEMU in general?

It is clearly stated right at the beginning of the relevant chapter in the Yocto documentation that they are different (see https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/qemu.html):

> **Note**
>
> This implementation is not the same as QEMU in general.

However, after briefly reading through the rest of the chapter I do not see much of a difference.

Right now I am trying to decide what the best way to install QEMU is. I'm not sure if it matters if I use the QEMU implementation that comes with the YoctoSDK/Poky or downloaded from https://www.qemu.org/. Does anyone have a specific example where one implementation might be favored?